# Tag-merge syscalls -> system-calls

Tags: discussion, tags

There are two tags that seem to be split with the same meaning,

- [syscalls](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/syscalls)
- [system-calls](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/system-calls)

Perhaps the top could become a tag-synonym of the bottom?

Comment: Are system call questions on topic? If yes, good news.

Answer (score 10):

I’ve created [the relevant synonym](https://unix.stackexchange.com/tags/system-calls/synonyms), all it needs now is votes. Any user with an answer score of 5 or more on [system-calls](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/system-calls) can vote! I had misread the requirements previously, it turns out [there are quite a few users meeting the requirements](https://unix.stackexchange.com/tags/system-calls/topusers). (The answer score is the number of upvotes on answers in the tag, minus the number of downvotes on answers in the tag.)

Comment: I tried to vote for this but I lack the required score on the tag :(